# Is the phrase ねぇ、ちょっと寄ってかない？ written incorrectly?

Tags: grammar, words

ねぇ、ちょっと寄ってかない？ I came across this banner in a chat room. Would か need to be added if its a question? I understand the phrase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This か is **normally** omitted.

As you know, か after a polite marker (です/ます) is very common (～ですか? / ～ますか? / ～ませんか?). However, in casual speech, か is rarely used, and people use rising intonation instead.

- 食べる？(↗)　Wanna eat?
- 食べない？(↗)　Don't wanna eat? / Why don't we eat?

Actually, adding か here makes the sentence sound fairly **masculine and blunt**.

- 食べるか？ (masculine and blunt)
- 食べないか？ (masculine and blunt)

For example, you may see this form used by a stereotyped stubborn father in fiction. In reality, I would say speakers of standard Japanese almost never speak like this. (Um, maybe male pet owners may speak like this to their cats or dogs...)

Presumably this "ねぇ、ちょっと寄ってかない？" is said by a woman (this phrase is known as a [Japanese *hosutesu*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_and_hostess_clubs)'s classic way of touting), so there should **not** be か at the end.

Answer (score 0):

In casual speech, the か is can be omitted. If you raise the pitch on the last syllable (like you would in English) the phrase is understood to be a question. In casual writing (like texting, or in this case a chat room), you can't add pitch, so punctuation serves to mark it as a question.

> 寄ってこない{LLLLHH}？ (Red bar indicates pitch, not emphasis)
>
> この本を読んだことある｛LLLLLHH｝？

Comment: 「[寄ってこない]{LHHHLH}？」「[読んだことある]{HLLLLHL}⤴？」になると思います。質問の例文は「寄って[来]{こ}ない？」じゃなくて「[寄ってかない]{LHHHHH}？」(← colloquial pronunciation of 「寄って[行]{い}かない？」)ですけどね。。。